# Can't interact with stencil image (blender 4.0)

Tags: texture-painting

I try to learn texture paint, but I cant find a way to interact with stencil

It seems that all settings are correct, but nothing changes. Could you help me?

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hello, do you mean that once you select the stencil you can't move, rotate or scale it? The shortcuts should be RMB, Ctrl RMB et Shift RMB, maybe show a screenshot of your 3D view?